# CommandButton doing different things

Tags: jsf

I have a commandbutton on my datatable wich I need that sometimes show a report (.jasper) in a new tab with the *target=blank* and depending on the situation of the item just put the information in another page (a registration one) without the new tab.

Is that possible or the only solution is two buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try conditional expression language:

```
target="#{myBean.myCondition ? 'blank' : 'self'}"
```

This way you will only get `target="blank"` when your bean's condition is true.

Comment: It will work on any attribute that will take expression language.

Comment: I understood how and made it work here but what I need is something that can be changed dinamically. by doing this way the code gets blank or self when the screen starts and then never changes again.

Comment: Can't you just use Ajax for that?

Comment: No, ajax won't work in this case. When you display a PDF file in a browser, behind the scenes you're downloading the file and let the browser display it, and you can't download files using Ajax.

Comment: I guess theres a easy way of doing it with javascript... but thats a whole other story.